# Библиотека для работы с Cassandra в CI

Tags: php, codeigniter, библиотеки, cassandra

Посоветуйте, пожалуйста, библиотеку для работы с Cassandra в CI.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Посмотрите [здесь](http://planetcassandra.org/client-drivers-tools/#PHP) и [здесь](https://packagist.org/search/?q=cassandra).

Comment: Спасибо! Вы могли бы обратить внимание на другую,схожу тему:
http://hashcode.ru/questions/354886/nosql-%D0%B4%D0%BE%D0%B1%D0%B0%D0%B2%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5-%D0%B7%D0%B0%D0%BF%D0%B8%D1%81%D0%B8-%D0%B2-apache-cassandra